# C# error in application

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I implemented my site and suddenly im catching an error in the `global.asax application_error` which states the following:

```
Error Caught in Application_Error event Error in: http://www.mydomain.com/styles/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs= Error Message:A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
SOURCE: System.Web FORM:  QUERYSTRING:  TARGETSITE: Void ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() STACKTRACE:    at
System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()     
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ValidateRequestExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I know this is the data for an image , but i cant find out how and why this is happen.
Any ideas?

Chr.

Answer (score 5):

It's an illegal URL:

> http://www.mydomain.com/styles/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs

The colon is a special character (signifiying protocol separator, port separator, or password separator)

As Hasan mentions, you can turn this validation off.  But in truth, you should avoid having URLs like this that are just just completely invalid.  Instead, [URL-encode it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) (the part after "data").

Comment: This is the best answer! The asker should mark this answer as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by a CSS minifier tool incorrectly altering data:image URLs: [Why would CSS data-URIs be logged as 404 requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17279643/251011)